# Python and Pytest Disagree on Import Style

Tags: python, python-3.x, namespaces, pytest, python-import

## Trying to Find an Import Style That Works for Python and Pytest

### Context

I'm trying to write a script and use **pytest 6.2.1** to verify it as I go.
Throughout, I had my unit tests passing in pytest, but when I was finished and tried to run the script directly, I got errors about imports.
Since then, I've gone back and forth changing the imports subtly to try find an import style that would work in both contexts.
I've not been successful.

### Code Structure and Contents

#### Directory Structure

I've set up my directory structure like so:

```
pkg
|-- __init__.py
|-- mod1.py
|-- mod2.py
`-- tests
    |-- __init__.py
    |-- mod1_test.py
    `-- mod2_test.py
```

I'm attempting to use different modules for distinct functionality.
I added `__init__.py` files to make a package and subpackage so that namespaces wouldn't conflict.
This script is part of a larger directory, and I didn't want collisions with other unrelated modules elsewhere.
I also wanted tests in their own directory, to be separate from the code, and to mimic the code structure.

#### File Contents

The `__init__.py` files are empty.
Below is the contents of each mod and test file:

```py
# mod1.py
from pkg import mod2


def fnc1():
    print("foo")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    fnc1()
    mod2.fnc2()
```

```py
# mod2.py
from pkg import mod1


def fnc2():
    print("bar")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    fnc2()
    mod1.fnc1()
```

```py
# mod1_test.py
from pkg import mod1

def test_fnc1():
    mod1.fnc1()
    pass
```

```py
# mod2_test.py
from pkg import mod2

def test_fnc2():
    mod2.fnc2()
    pass
```

### Errors

#### Script Works in Pytest, but Errors if Called Directly

If the code runs in pytest, I get the following error when calling the script directly:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/pkg/mod1.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pkg import mod2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pkg'
```

#### Script Works if Called Directly, but Errors in Pytest

I have also tried to make changes to the code so that it runs when called directly.
Namely, reworking the imports from `from pkg import mod2` to `import mod2`.
When the code runs without error if the script is called directly, I get the following error instead upon calling pytest:

```
______________________ ERROR collecting pkg/tests/mod1_test.py ______________________
ImportError while importing test module '/path/to/pkg/tests/mod1_test.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
/path/to/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py:127: in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
pkg/tests/mod1_test.py:1: in <module>
    from pkg import mod1
pkg/mod1.py:1: in <module>
    import mod2
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mod2'
```

### Summary

I'd greatly appreciate suggestions on how to structure my imports so that they work for both contexts.
It's important to me to use unit tests, so I want a style that allows me to validate my code with pytest.
However, the code should also work outside of testing, so I need a solution which is functional broadly.

Ideally, a solution would not require end-users of the script to take any action before calling the script.
I'd prefer the onus to be on me, possibly requiring me to rework how tests are structured, while allowing the script to be called seamlessly.

Answer (score 2):

It is hard to tell what you made different in your tests, since you did notpost their code.

The above project will work if the directory containing the `pkg` directory itself is in the PythonPath, or if `pkg` is properly installed as a package, after `pip install -e .` on this root dir or equivalent.

If you start your code run from the folder containing `pkg`, without any changes it should work as well, since the current directory is pre-pended to the python path when running scripts.

If you have a proper configuration for the package tests either in pyproject.toml, pytest.ini or setup.cfg files, it is possible that pytest will "see" the pkg package while Python won't (due to it not being installed).

And definetelly: it won't work if it the pkg is not installed and you try to run `mod1` or `mod2` from inside the `pkg` folder.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. I edited the question to add test contents, if that's helpful.

You're right about running the script from the directory containing `pkg`, I hadn't noticed that.

My script will be shared with others I work with. While I can `pip install -e .` for me, ideally I wouldn't have to get everyone to do that.

Would you be able to suggest anything I could do which would allow others to call the script without setup?  The imports I used under **Script Works if Called Directly, but Errors in Pytest** seemed to allow this, but didn't work with the unit tests.